# Vlookup Category Number in Range and (twist) name

Tags: excel, range, vlookup

Say I have the following table:

```
Airport Start   END Bank
SEA 7:40    9:29    1
SEA 9:30    11:29   2
SEA 11:30   13:09   3
SEA 13:10   14:34   4
SEA 14:35   7:54    5
ATL 7:55    9:44    1
ATL 9:45    11:44   2
ATL 11:45   13:24   3
ATL 13:25   14:49   4
ATL 14:50   8:09    5
```

I would like to be able to find the bank number given a spreadsheet with the following information:

I have in Column A the Station and in Column B the Time

```
SEA    11:30
```

The expected result is :3

```
ATL    11:30
```

The expected result is :2

Having the time, I know how to seach in a given range with vlookup but don't know how to differentiate between Stations.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using and describe what's wrong with it?

Comment: I can do a normal vlookup on time for columns Start and End.  The problem is how to tell excel to look under SEA times or ATL times depending on my request.

Comment: How do you request it? Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(F6,A3:B15,3,1). That returns the bank but does not differentiate between airports

Comment: What is on F6? The question needs some more details. Please don't answer on the comments, try to edit the question and make it understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question by using an array formula.

=INDEX($K$3:$K$22,MAX(($E$3:$E$22=$A1)*($B1>=$G$3:$G$22)*($B1<=$H$3:$H$22)*ROW($G$3:$G$22))-2)

The lookup table is as such:

K has the bank numbers

E Station Range

G Beginning Time Range

H Ending Time Range

My data is:

A1: Station

B1: Time